# How save this data of mongoose I have not understood .save() working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I also did not see YCampDB in my dbs.

```
var express = require(`express`)
var app = express()
let bodyParser = require(`body-parser`)
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`)
mongoose.connect = ("mongodb://localhost:27017/YCampDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

SCHEMA SETUP

```
 const campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
        name: String,
        image: String
});

var Campground = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema)

    campground = new Campground({ name: "john carter", 
    image: "photo-1537565266759-3ixlib=rb- 
    1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"
     })

   campground.save();
```

When I am wanted to show YCampDB it is not showing it showing:

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the syntax:

`mongoose.connect = ("mongodb://localhost:27017/YCampDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })`

The above syntax is wrong, it should be:
`mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/YCampDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })`